# mesh1D.py example in FiPy fails if run in parallel

Tags: python, fipy, trilinos

I downloaded FiPy months ago and this week I decided to test its parallel feature. So I tried to run the mesh1D.py example I got from [github](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/tree/master/examples/diffusion) using

**$ mpirun -np 2 python examples/diffusion/mesh1D.py**

Two viewers pop up, each solving half of the problem like it was supposed to be. After the first problem is completed (*explicit transient diffusion*), it asks me to press return to proceed.

**True

True

Explicit transient diffusion. Press <'return> to proceed...Explicit transient diffusion. Press <'return> to proceed...**

But nothing happens when I press return. I know little about parallel programming, but is it normal that both processors are asking to press *return*? Shouldn't this part of the code be handled by only one core?
Some extra information: the mesh1D example works fine if I don't use mpi. And I have run the [parallel.py test](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/tree/master/examples) as well, which works correctly.

I'm using python 2.7.14, Trilinos 12.12.1, FiPy 3.2 and mpi4py 3.0.0

Comment: ~What platform are you on?~ Never mind. I see it. It's a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/usnistgov/fipy/issues/669). Thanks for reporting it.